# Running executable from CreateProcess... From Outlook

Tags: c++, outlook, createprocess

This is very specific, and I have very little to go on, but I am at my wits end.

Here's the scenario:

My c++ application runs an executable using CreateProcess. The Process Attributes, Thread Attributes and Environment are all inherited from the application.

The executable loads a DLL.

When I run my application normally, all is fine.

When I launch my application from Outlook ("Open" my applications data file, as an email attachment, from Outlook, which launches my application) the CreateProcess succeeds, but the executable that is run returns immediately with a return code of 1, and there is nothing in std out or std err.

Investigation shows that the Path environment variable in my application is the same when it is run normally, and when it is run from Outlook *except* that Outlook adds its directory to the path. All other paths are the same.

The executable I am running is g++ cross compiler.

I know this is a tiny amount to go on, but I'm hoping someone has had a similar experience.

Comment: Have you write writing logs to a file to see what it's doing? Have you checked that it has the required permissions/elevation?

Comment: Perhaps it could not locate dll, because of different working directory. Did you add path to your dll to the system `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: The dll is in the same path as the executable, so it should be able to find it.
In terms of logging from the executable, it isn't reporting anything (not stdout or stderr) so there is nothing to log.

Comment: If you are on windows, install Windbg.exe and use gflags to launch windbg.exe whenever Yourapp.exe starts
https://bugslasher.net/2011/03/26/how-to-debug-a-process-as-soon-as-it-starts-with-windbg-or-visual-studio-2010/

From here you can debug what your app does when Outlook launches it.
You can also use gflags.exe to turn on "loader snaps" which will catch any dll issues as Ari0nhh suggests.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that